# Am unable to add file in git repository

Tags: addition

Am trying to add file , keep on failing

[image]

Comment: Some one plz help me

Comment: Try `git add -A` command.
Or any particular file means.
Do `git status` and use `git add <file_name_from_git_status_command>`.

Comment: Instead of image, try copy paste the text in your question.

Comment: Are you sure you have the directory named `folder`? Try run `ls -l` and see what you have in your working directory (`devops-project`).

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text, paste it in a block of code instead

Answer (score 0):

There are no files in `folder`. You need to `git add folder`to add the empty folder or make sure to put some files into `folder`